# Making simultaneous AJAX calls to separate Django views

Tags: ajax, django

I have a Django view that runs a particular function when a POST request is received.

Snippet:

```
def run_function(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        run_some_function()
```

This is called via AJAX as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    'type' : 'POST',
    'url' : '/run_function/',
    'data' : data,
    'success' : function(json) {
            // Display results to user
        }
    });
```

This works as expected. However, this particular function can take a while to run, so I want to display progress information to the user.

Luckily, I have another function that can return the progress (an integer between 0-100) of the task.

Snippet:

```
def get_progress(request):
    progress = calculate_progress()
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(progress), content_type="application/json")
```

I can then make an AJAX call every X seconds to get the progress and update my progress bar:

```
function check_progress() {
    $.ajax({
        'type' : 'POST',
        'url' : '/get_progress/',
        'success' : function(response) {
            if (response >= 100) {
                // Update progress bar to 100% and clearInterval
            } else {
                // Update the progress bar based on the value returned by get_progress
            }
        }
    });
}

var check = setInterval(check_progress, 500);
```

The problem is...how can I do both simultaneously? I need to be able to make the AJAX call to run the function **and** make the AJAX calls to monitor progress, at the same time.

Are there any suggestions for how to accomplish this? Or perhaps a better design than making two AJAX calls?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Make a single ajax call and let the handling view call as many additional views as you like.

Comment: @Wtower Interesting idea, but how would I pass the data from the view back to the JavaScript? Let's say I start a new process to run the function. Then, while it's running, I have the view call another view that returns an HTTPResponse. Won't it just return that to the calling view? In this design, I don't understand how to update the JS side dynamically while the function is running.

Comment: Right. Then refactor your code and place common code into python modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The A in AJAX stands for Asynchronous. You don't need to do anything special. If you have your views and progress sorted out, all you need to do is:

```
$.ajax({
    'type' : 'POST',
    'url' : '/run_function/',
    'data' : data,
    'success' : function(json) {
            // Display results to user
        }
    });
var check = setInterval(check_progress, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks! I did read that many browsers limit you to two simultaneous AJAX requests, but right now that's all I need.

Comment: Yes, it's very unlike that this will cause more than two requests to be running at a time.